# dragged icon transparent in gtk+

Tags: gtk

while dragging a icon from GTKIconView , the dragged icon (which appears below the cursor) should be transparent .How do i achive that in gtk+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a PNG file with transparent background.